# Passing javascript parameter into flask/sqlAlchemy/python database

Tags: javascript, python, python-3.x, flask, sqlalchemy

Trying to pass javascript number variable with GET request into flask/sqlAlchemy/python file so that I can sort and retrieve data using that parameter

The variable I am referring to is user1

See below for code that I have tried. I know that I am close but do not know where to go from here. Right now I have hardcoded the variable "user1" to 32 but will be making it dynamic once the basics work.

As of right now I am trying to pass user1 with

JAVASCRIPT FILE:

```
    const user1 = "32"; // PASSING THIS VARIABLE IN
    try {
      const response = await fetch(
        `http://localhost:5000/produce/<${user1}>/`,
        {
          method: "GET",
          headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" }
        }
      );
```

PYTHON FILE:

```
@app.route('/produce/<user1>', methods=['GET'])
def produce_get_user(user1):
    user_id=user1
    print("INCOMING ID", user_id)
```

The print statement in the python file never gets executed.

### The following is the message outputted by the backend python file:

### [25/Mar/2019 12:17:03] "OPTIONS /produce/%3C32%3E/ HTTP/1.1" 404 -

The following are the two messages outputted by the javascript:

### error#1

### OPTIONS http://localhost:5000/produce/%3C32%3E/ 404 (NOT FOUND)

### error#2

### Access to fetch at 'http://localhost:5000/produce/%3C32%3E/' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy:

Comment: don't put the `<` and `>` around the parameter in your `fetch` call. That's not the same URL your backend will accept.

Comment: and as for the CORS issue, you likely want to install [this](https://flask-cors.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)